# Listening for global keyboard events while computer is locked

Tags: c#, keyboard, globalevent

I'm experimenting with keyboard events and what you can do with them and I've found alot of tutorials and open source libraries to listen for keyboard events in other processes. I came up with the idea to create a simple 'hack' to lock the computer and then listen for the keyboard events. I figured I could force the user to input their password to unlock their computer and then I would've listened to the user input and thus obtaining the password specified. Here is the simple sample code I found on the internet which will listen for global keyboard events:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

This works out quiet well, but for some reason there seems to be a exception when listening to keyboard inputs when the computer is locked? I'm not sure why it doesn't work, perhaps it's a security thing. Anyways it would be awesome if one could do this.

Comment: It *is* a security thing.  I doubt there's a way around it without hacking the OS.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for the _very_ quick answer. But would this be possible to achieve if you were to run another fake identical application or a cracked version of the application and then get the user to think the computer is locked?

Comment: Give me a credit card number (and the security code on the back), and I'll tell you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is on Windows, the locked screen is actually a different [Window Station](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and is not owned by the interactive user, so therefore the interactive user cannot interact with it in any way (as a security measure). To interact with the lock screen, and logon in general, take a look at creating a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)